# R: read from file and write to character vector

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm newbie in R so sorry for my very basic question :-)

I'm trying to read from a simple text file and write to a character vector.
The file is basically a list of names with no headers, such as:

ibm

microsoft

amazon

I'd like to read from it and write to a character vector like this:
user.list <- c("ibm","microsoft","amazon")

Tryied with read.data read.table with no success...

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text file contains one and only one item per line, one can use the `readLines()` function to read the data to a vector of characters.

```
rawData <- "ibm
microsoft
amazon
hp
apple"

companies <- readLines(textConnection(rawData))
str(companies)
```

...and the output:

```
> companies <- readLines(textConnection(rawData))
> str(companies)
 chr [1:5] "ibm" "microsoft" "amazon" "hp" "apple"
>
```

Comment: Yes the text file contains one row per item. The problem was solved using ReadLines, also other suggestions are interesting and works! Thank you guys for your time